# How can I make a strip that goes from a specific point to all the way to the right regardless of screen resolution?

Tags: css, fullscreen, strip

I am intending to have a header with an image I can repeat starting from about the middle (float:left; to position it) and I'd like it to reach the very right side no matter screen resolution here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="strip"></div>
```

css:

```
#strip{width:1px;height:302px;background:url('repeat.png') 0 0 repeat-x;float:left;}
```

any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I changed Aniket's fiddle)

Added css:

```
body {overflow-x:hidden}
#strip {margin-left:50%}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/426LB/4/

Comment: that would cover the entire screen and I just want from a certain position and on, the position itself isn't fixed as the main image moves with the screen's resolution =/

Answer (score 0):

```
div#strip {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Div is a block element, and will automatically try to fill up all the available width.

JSFiddle here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qBvLC/)

Comment: almost! you see I forked your fiddle here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/h7SQL/1/ what I want is that the strip doesn't get detached from the left div (#against) and after a certain width, it happens =/

Comment: yes, in the sense that it's directly next to the other div (perfect) but it should also go all the way to the right. (end of the screen)

Comment: The easiest way for that is probably this: http://jsfiddle.net/h7SQL/9/ Since you set a fixed width on the left item, you can place that margin on the right item. As long as you do not have variable width of the left item, this should do.

Comment: well the item itself doesn't has a variable with but if the screen resolution gets bigger (wider window) then would it still work?

Comment: Yes, the righthand item should still grow to fit the screen, but the width of the lefthand item and the margin of the right one needs to be constant.

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2399/discussion-between-luis-armando-and-andreas-carlbom)

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/426LB/

It's just that the width needs to be set at 100% and it's done.

Comment: yes except I want it to be fixed to a position on its left. However that position should be wherever the div before it (#against) loads according to screen resolution: http://jsfiddle.net/h7SQL/1/

Comment: i am not able to get what exactly you mean? Could you elaborate? Or could you give a link with a similar thing?